# Where does phtml-file get its data in magento2?

Tags: magento2

In the file app/code/Magento/Bundle/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/summary.phtml

On line 46 there is variable "data" being called:

```
<script data-template="bundle-option" type="text/x-magento-template">
<div><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('%1 x %2 x #', '<%- data._quantity_ %>', '<%- data._label_ %>') ?></div>
```

I need to know where this variable "data" is created in the backend?
Is it from a block or the model?

Comment: Just in case you did not notice it: It's a JavaScript variable, not a PHP variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Magento/Bundle/view/frontend/web/js/product-summary.js](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Bundle/view/frontend/web/js/product-summary.js#L103) file. JS render this template with data.